# Translating an application using resources in WPF

Tags: wpf, localization, silverlight-4.0, resourcedictionary

I saw in Silverlight 4.0 Business application that is it possible to have all the strings in one resource file that you could , potentially, change depending of the user so that each user has its own experience (ie language for example)

I'd like to be able to do this in WPF also, so I though about moving that stuff from Silverlight to WPF, but the thing is I don't really understand all the code behind this so I'm afraid that I'd make a lot of mistake on the way and end up with nothing.

Does anyone knows exactly how this part works or have a good suggestion of an online tutorial on how to integrate this into WPF or at least, understand it enough to be able to reproduce it in WPF ?

Edit : BTW : By translating, I do not necessarily mean from french to english and so on. We want to be able to change the label according to client. Ex : Change the word machine for boat of resource, etc. I would like to be able to have those changes editable to the user (using a UI we will create ourselves).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this whitepaper -

> This project includes a whitepaper
>   with code samples to help Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   developers localize their
>   applications. The whitepaper compares
>   LocBaml and classic Resx approaches
>   with pros and cons.

WPF Localization Guidance : http://wpflocalization.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'll have a look at that, though I am not sure if that will do what I want. The problem all comes with the fact that it is not translation per say, but the fact that each user may want to use other words for the same label. Is there a way to assign resource using external files (ex : I have a list of keys in a file and load them into whatever structure needed to make it work) ? That way the user could customize each label accordingly. Then I would use those resources within my label. I'm still pretty new to using resources, so this might be trivial, but not to me.
Thanls